# how to get datetime to int in django? use datetime only hour and minute

Tags: python, django, datetime

I wanted to save the time as an int type so I could get the difference between the two times.

i import datetime and try to like this

```
now = datetime.now()
```

but i get this : 2017-11-18 05:47:35.262111

how to get only hour and minute to int

ex) 0547

I could not solve it.

Comment: Can not you try it this way?
    now = str(datetime.now())
    
    nun=0
    for s in now:
        if type(s) == type(1):
            nun +=s

Comment: @PetarP How? He wants only the hours and minutes fields, not UNIX time.

Comment: i have a error this '''invalid literal for int() with base 10: '{}{}.format(now.hour, now.minute)''''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the hour and minute attributes and cast them to integer.

```
 import datetime
    hour_now = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour) # for hour
    minute_now = int(datetime.datetime.now().minute) # for minute
```

Comment: thank to your help! 
I have one last question.

I would like to make single digit numbers look like 07 instead of 7.

Comment: if hour_now < 10:    hour_now = "0%d"%(hour_now)

above code will return a string, you won't be able to perform integer operations on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *.time()* and slice its hour and minute part.

```
str(datetime.now().time())[:5].replace(':','')
# OUTPUT: '0951'
```

> An ***`int`*** doesn't have leading zeros, or any other formatting
>   property. It is just a number. If you want to include a leading zero, I recommend using ***`string`***.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to you, I could solve it.

like this

```
hour = datetime.now().hour
minute = datetime.now().minute

if minute >10:
    return str(hour)+str(minute)
else:
    return str(hour)+"0"+str(minute)
```